# Rails image asset tag helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails you can just a regular html `img` tag in your templates, what is the purpose of using an asset tag helper?

```
<%= image_tag "header.png" %>
```

vs.

```
<img src="header.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the image_tag also uses the asset path helpers. So it will automatically use '/assets/header.png'. Also if you have asset digest turned on I think it will automatically use '/assets/header-asdfasd.png' on production.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, any image_tag would be transformed into HTML `img` tag.

I think Rails just provides some way to create HTML in Ruby/Rails way in case you are not a HTML guy, of course you can just use HTML `img` tag if you like.

Not only Rails, some other render utils, like Razor in C# , provide the similar feature.